# The subreport with its own query is rendering empty (only header is showing)

Tags: jasper-reports, subreport

I'm trying to execute one report with one subreport and it is filling only the main report. I generate the reports dinamically in Java and I fill it with:

```
JasperFillManager.fillReport(report, paramsMap, DataSourceUtils.getConnection(SingletonSpring.getDataSource()))
```

The jrxml report generated is this one:

```
    ....

<parameter name="Subreport0" class="net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperReport"/>

    ....

<queryString>
    <![CDATA[...]]]>
</queryString>

    ....

<band>
    <frame>
        <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="960" height="0" uuid="d6549c83-20a3-45b6-bd5e-0f2a545b9aec"/>
        <subreport>
            <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="960" height="0" uuid="5c65dc87-4ff9-4126-ade6-0bf7e76cce5c"/>

            ...[some parameters]...

            <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_DATA_SOURCE}]]></dataSourceExpression>
            <subreportExpression><![CDATA[$P{Subreport0}]]></subreportExpression>
        </subreport>
    </frame>
</band>
```

In the `SubReport0` parameter I pass the subreport generated. In the subrepport there are a distinct one query.

When I execute this the generated pdf fill main report data, but not subreport data, only the header.

Comment: You should post the snippet with `Subreport0` parameter initialization and passing it via parameters

Comment: Did you try to pass connection (not the `dataSourceExpression`) to the subreport?

Comment: No, I din't try this. I'm going try it

Comment: Perfect! Now it's working!
Thank you!

Comment: You are welcome :)

Answer (score 0):

Because the subreport has its own dataset (you wrote that it is query based) you don't need pass the parent datasource.

Most likely that the issue will be solved after passing the connection. Try to pass the parent report's connection (of course in case if both reports using the same DB) with help of `$P{REPORT_CONNECTION}` parameter and `connectionExpression` attribute instead of passing the datasource with `dataSourceExpression` attribute.

The subreport element will be like this:

```
<subreport>
    <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="960" height="0"/>

    ...[some parameters]...

    <connectionExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_CONNECTION}]]></connectionExpression>
    <subreportExpression><![CDATA[$P{Subreport0}]]></subreportExpression>
</subreport>
```